# Why the order of elements in HashSet's keySet changes from run to run?

Tags: java

I have some code utilizing standard Java collections: arrays, ArrayDeques, HashMaps, Lists, HashSets.
My code is expected to be deterministic: the hash codes of all the elements, the initial contents of the collections, and etc. are expected to depend only on the input data. The final output of the code is produced from a `keySet()` of some HashMap.

I've noticed that the order of the elements in the resulting keySet sometimes changes from run to run. What does it mean?

- Some standard collections have non-deterministic behavior (e.g., hash codes of some internal objects are non-deterministic)?
- My own code is actually non-deterministic (e.g., I forgot to properly override hashCode() for some class)? This might mean I have a bug somewhere (that wasn't caught by the tests yet), that's why I'm concerned.
- Something else?

This happens quite consistently with JDK 1.7.0_60, x86 on Windows 7 x64.
Allegedly, this does not happen (or happens rarely) with JDK 1.8.0_05.
Also, the order of elements in the resulting keySet (and the overall order in which the data items are processed) changes when switching between the above JDKs.

I suspect, this is some feature of a HashSet, but could not trace it to a specific line of code.

**UPD 1** I do not really need deterministic sets, and I know that HashSet provides no guarantees. I'm just trying to find the reason of non-deterministic behavior. If it is in library code - fine. But if it is in my code - I'll likely have to fix it. Hence the question.

**UPD 2** Of course, I managed to find the answer right after posting the question. Just in the beginning of 1.7's HashMap.java:

```
/**
 * A randomizing value associated with this instance that is applied to
 * hash code of keys to make hash collisions harder to find. If 0 then
 * alternative hashing is disabled.
 */
transient int hashSeed = 0;
```

In 1.8, this randomization doesn't seem to be there any more.

Comment: Unless a particular Collection is guaranteed to maintain order, iteration rules care only that all elements are visited once.

Comment: +1 Interesting! You should answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer. You won't get any rep points, but it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying here what is already included in the question. A quick look through the sources showed that in 1.7, HashMap indeed has non-deterministic behavior, and each instance seeds the hashes of the elements with some random value. In 1.8, the implementation was changed, and the randomization doesn't seem to be there any more.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation of HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a stable ordered HashSet, then you should be using [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) per the javadoc,

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order

And per the [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) javadoc,

> ... makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set