# In which situation is HashMap keySet() ordered undeterministic

Tags: java, hashmap

The docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html say

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map;
> In particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
> over time.

However I ran some experiment

```
var first = new HashMap<String, Object>();
first.put("a", 1)
first.put("b", 2);
first.put("c", null)
```

`first.keySet()` order is always `[a, b, c]`

So if I have `String` or `Integer` as the key for `HashMap` then will the order be the same and deterministic for any other `HashMap` instance for the same Key and value?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? This is implementation detail and your code should not depend on it.

Comment: [Why does a HashMap sometimes print in natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357126/why-does-a-hashmap-sometimes-print-in-natural-order) isn't *quite* the same question, but it explains a lot of what you're seeing.

Comment: In all situations.

Comment: A single-byte string's hashcode will be equivalent to `bytes[0] & 0xff`. So the hashcodes of `"a", "b", "c"` are `97,98,99` respectively. With the modulus from hashmap, it's no wonder this specific case is stored sequentially. Your experiment isn't terrible, but you're forgetting about your assumptions (that single-byte strings are representative of all strings, and for their `#hashCode` this is not true).

Answer (score 3):

> In which situation is `HashMap::keySet()` ordered non-deterministically?

In short ... when any of the preconditions 1, 2 or 3 (below!) are not true.

---

The javadoc says what it says.  The `HashMap` implementation does not **guarantee** any particular order for the key set.

The fact that the javadoc does not guarantee an order does NOT mean that the order cannot be predicted in some circumstances.

As your observations bear out!

In practice the order of the keys in a `HashMap` will be *deterministic* if all of the following are true:

1. The `HashMap` implementation does not change<sup>1</sup>.
2. The key classes `equals` and `hashCode` methods follow the relevant invariants specified in the `Object` javadocs.  (And in some cases, the `compareTo` method may be involved as well.)
3. The key classes `hashCode` is predictable based on a key's value.

If in addition:

4. The map is created with the same initial capacity and load factor.
5. The keys' insertion (and deletion) order is the same.

... you will get the same key set order repeatably.

Indeed, if all of the above are true AND you have complete information / knowledge about the `HashMap` implementation and so on, then you could<sup>2</sup> actually *a priori predict* the key order with 100% accuracy.

Note that 2 and 3 are satisfied for `Integer` and `String`.  Indeed the javadocs for both classes specify the precise values returned by `hashCode()`.  That is why you are seeing the same key order repeatably for those key types in your experiments.

Note: you probably shouldn't make use of these properties in an application, since the javadocs don't actually guarantee them.

---

<sup>1 - Or more precisely *while* it does not change.  In fact, the implementations of `HashMap` have changed between different Java versions.  As a consequence the key order can be different if you run your tests on platforms with different versions of Java.  It is also conceivable that a future implementation of `HashMap` could be made *deliberately* non-deterministic ... though I can't imagine why they would do this.

2. The process would be very tedious and time consuming to do by hand, and I'm not going to explain it.  But [Why does a HashMap sometimes print in natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357126) may help you understand what you would need to do.</sup>

Comment: A comment to your foot note 1: some versions of Java 1.7 had dilebartely added code that makes the hashcodes appear non-deterministic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771793/why-the-order-of-elements-in-hashsets-keyset-changes-from-run-to-run and https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/4824bf600d5033f6041d6d98c359d5c22961e2cc/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L205

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by doc that order is indeed non-deterministic.

Try running the code with more data in HashMap to see the difference.

Set is unordered by design.

If order is necessary for your requirement (in main data structure) try **LinkedHashMap** which maintains order of insertion. (As it implements LinkedList internally.)

Hope this helps.